# Destroying thread, during scrolling AbsListView

Tags: android

I want to solve next problem and hope for your help. I have got AbsListView with a set of images. Images are inflated by background thread which download it from the internet. I make this thread, because I don't want to impede the UI thread. So when user scrolls AbsListView I want to destroy the background thread and start it after stop scrolling.

To do it I need at least override ***onScroll*** method, but I don't know what should I write in it's body, because when I try to use ***Thread.destroy()*** method (which is deprecated) I got ***NoSuchMethodError***.

When I define it as null if onScroll, It set the downloaded images into scrolling items.

Please, I need your advice how to cope with this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is generally not recommended to use threading capabilities by extending Thread.
Android has a wonderful thing called AsyncTask http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

It's easy to use, and has a convenience methods, such as .cancel();
And if java api method is deprecated you shouldn't use it.

Comment: I thought about AsyncTask using, but my problem is that every item from my AbsListView has it's handler which handle message sended by background thread, and I can't realise how should I apply this mechanism with AsyncTask. But no matter, thank you for respond.

Comment: AsyncTask, dumbed down, has the same functionality as the regular Thread. I don't see why can't you do handler posting from doInBackground, just like you do from run() in your regular thread.

Comment: As an example (don't know if it'll be helpfull). In one my app, I had a list of video thumbs. The dataset in the list consisted of objects, that had a flag (boolean thumbLoading). Activity also had a cache for thumbs. So when list called getView() it first asked the cache if it has a thumb for a particular position, if not, it asked the object (that must be displayed for this position) isThumbLoading, if false, it started an AsyncTask to load a thumb for this position and set the flag thumbLoading to true.

Comment: AsyncTask loaded image, put it in cache, changed flag, and called notifyDataSetChanged(). getView() asked for this position again and since it already was in cache it just displayed the image. Worked like a charm. But of course it was a relatively small list and small thumbs. This variant will eat your processor if user has scrolled a long list to a great length.

Comment: But how should I use an AsyncTask object if I nedd to pass it several different objects, to use it in doInBackground()?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below article for a discussion of approaches to stopping a `Thread` in Java.

- [How to Stop a Thread or a Task](http://forward.com.au/javaProgramming/HowToStopAThread.html)

I'm not convinced that an `AsyncTask` would be a good fit for your situation, as the `cancel()` method does not actually stop the processing that is occurring in `doInBackground()`, it merely prevents `onPostExecute()` from being called and instead calls `onCancelled()`.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)

mayInterruptIfRunning - true if the thread executing this task should be interrupted;

Comment: Setting it to `true` will only *attempt* to interrupt the background task, in my testing it has never actually succeeded in doing so.

Comment: Also, In my opinion to use AsyncTask in most effective way I should create it as inner class in my Activity, that give me one more reference to it.

Comment: @teoREtik, you don't *have* to write it as an inner class, you can write a constructor that accepts a `Context` as a parameter, and the `execute()` method will return a reference to itself.

Comment: But what should I do if I need to use an information which is defined in Activity (e.g. position of View in my AbsListView, number of Visible views)? How can I pass this info to AsyncTask?

Comment: You could pass it into the parameters for `doInBackground(Params... params)` (i.e. into `execute()`) or pass it into the constructor of the `AsyncTask`.  Check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

dude check out the library that async downloads/cache images from the web
https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper

one line of code.. simple as that =)